# jQuery cycle not working in IE8 - IE10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

Can someone help me figure out why a jQuery cycle call isn't working in the following website?

http://www.tamarackwellington.com/#floorkey

The problem is with the cycle setup under the "Floor Key" section.  For some reason only the arrows show up in IE8 to IE10, and the floorplans never do.

I had this code in a document.ready(), but that seemed to cause the same problem in other browsers as well.  Putting it in a window.load() solved it, except in IE8 to IE 10.

```
$(window).load(function() {

  $('#loadSold').show();

  $('#sold_slide').cycle({ 
        fx:     'scrollHorz', 
        speed:  'fast', 
        timeout: 0, 
        next:   '#nextsold', 
        prev:   '#prevsold'
    });
});
```

Comment: Is anything dynamically loaded on the page? All using `window` `load()` (instead of `document` `ready()`) has done is delay your code from running a little longer (until after initial images are loaded). That indicates something else is going on at load time.

Comment: There is a Google map (amenities) which loads various markers dynamically from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that adding a width / height value to each image in the slideshow did the trick.